# Keyboard shortcut for top of current page in a document

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, libreoffice-writer

When word-processing, is there a keyboard shortcut (in MS Word or LibreOffice Writer) to move to the top of the current page in the document? For example, if the cursor is midway down page 3, is there a shortcut that will bring the cursor to the *start* of page 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different programs have different shortcut keys.

In MS Word, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> will move your cursor to the top of the previous page ([Source1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/290938)).

In LibreOffice, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> will switch cursor between text and header ([Source2](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/Shortcut_Keys_for_Writer)). For LibreOffice, I was unable to find a shortcut that moves it exactly to the top of the page, but your comment states that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> twice works.

Comment: Do you know what happens if there is a *header* to the page, in Word? In LibreOffice the first use of Ctrl + Page Up takes you into the header... but pressing it again moves you to the top of the page (outside the header).

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the speed of reply. Particularly appreciate the links. (Perhaps using Ctrl+PageUp twice to purposefully get to the top of the page was not something the developers had in mind!)